# FireMonkey TClientDataSet Setting a Filter causes "Error Creating cfString" in OSX works fine in Windows

Tags: macos, c++builder, firemonkey, tclientdataset

I am having a problem setting a filter on a `TClientDataSet` when running on Mac OSX.  It works fine on Windows.

I get the error: `Error Creating cfString`

This is really easy for me to duplicate:

1. Create a new project.
2. Go to the **Project -> Deployment** menu item
3. Click the **Add Featured Files** button
4. Select **Midas Library** option and click OK
5. Add a `TClientDataSet` and name it `cdsData`
6. Add two fields:

   ```
   RecordGUID string (36) 
   Name string (40)
   ```
7. Create the Dataset (Right click and select **Create Dataset**)
8. Double click on the form to create an `OnCreate` event handler
9. Add the following code to the event

   ```
   void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
   {
       cdsData->Open();
       for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
       {
           cdsData->Append();
           cdsData->FieldByName("RecordGUID")->AsString = "UUID-" + IntToStr(i);
           cdsData->FieldByName("Name")->AsString = "Name " + IntToStr(i);
           cdsData->Post();
       }

       cdsData->Filter = "RecordGUID = 'UUID-4'";
       cdsData->Filtered = true;
   }
   ```
10. Add **OSX32** Target Platform to the project
11. Now Compile and Run the application.

You should get Error - `Error Creating CFString`.

Is there something special to do when adding a string as a filter in OSX?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: @RemyLebeau This line here causes the problem in OSX:  
`cdsData->Filtered = true;`

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem that has already been reported to Embarcadero:

[[MacOS] OS X 10.10 - Error Creating CFString](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=129512)

<sub>Oh wait, that ticket has an example that looks surprisingly like your code above :)</sub>

Comment: I'm waiting for a response back from them, but figured I'd try here in the meantime.  Thanks for formatting my post to look nicer :)

Comment: Considering that QualityCentral is now deprecated, you might consider re-posting the ticket to [QualityPortal](http://quality.embarcadero.com).